# How to create Mobile First server on IBM bluemix?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ibm-cloud, mobilefirst-server, ibm-mobile-services

I have created hybrid application with IBM MobileFirst 7.1. I have heard and read somewhere that you can host your MFP app on Bluemix. However, I cannot able find any process to do that on net and on the IBM site. We have a WAR file and adapter files to deploy on a Bluemix server but for that we have to create a server first, right? I have already created a Bluemix ID, which is valid for 1 month.

Can someone help explain how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are.

You have a tutorial for the evaluation path, giving you a pre-built server running on an IBM Container: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/evaluate/

You have a tutorial instructing you on how to create your own image using your MobileFirst Platform Foundation project, however note that for this you must be a paying IBM customer: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/ibm-containers/run/

Comment: finally i got worklight console. Created public ip for container so that i can acess it from anywhere. Thnx for your help. But How can I deploy new war file in that. Can you please help in that.

Comment: Follow the second tutorial.

Comment: I have downloaded sample project which is given in second link. Also created container already as I told you. So i have to follow Step 2: Prerequisites and onwards right?

Comment: i have completed 3 steps. now on running scrips I am facing some issue, By running ./initenv.sh after putting email id, pwd, org its asking for space so what should i pass in space? I am getting Error finding space 256MB. Can you please help me.

Comment: Please use google: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/admin/adminpublic.html#orgsandspaces

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110332/discussion-between-suhas-and-idan-adar).

Comment: hi idan i have completed all the process i can able to see container get created but can not able to view worklight console. all process completed succesfully. what is the problem can you  help me.

Comment: @suhas what is the exact problem you are facing? any logs you can pass? If you are a IBM customer - you should open a PMR to avoud pasting sensitive information like URLs and logs on stackoverflow